# Blazor App Razor Pages Routing With parameters

Tags: razor, blazor

trying to Use hyperlink column and performing routing on click

UriHelper.NavigateTo($"{ Employee.Link}/{Employee.EmployeeID.ToString()}/{Employee.Name}/{ Employee.Title}");

Not sure what to name the Razor page which will be retrieve using the dynamic link and how to initialize it with the required details

@page "/???????/{EmpID}/{Name}/{Title}"

it works when I have razor page named as Employee.link and initializing it with the Employee.link details

@page "/sara_clarck/{EmpID}/{Name}/{Title}"

but I do not want to create one razor page for each employee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you should need to pass to a new page is an ID.  Your receiving page, let's call it `/employees/{EmpID}`, should be able to look up the employee's name and title on its own, probably in the `OnInitializedAsync` override.

So something like:

**EmployeeViewer.razor**

```
@page "/employees/{EmpID:int}"

@if (DisplayEmp is not null)
{
    <SomeComponentThatDisplaysEmployeeInfo Employee=DisplayEmp />
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int EmpID { get; set; }

    public Employee? DisplayEmp = null;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DisplayEmp = MyDbService.GetEmployee(EmpID);
    }
}
```

As Shaun says, you can name the actual file whatever you want, as you specify the component's path as a page.  A component can even have multiple routes defined, e.g. your main page could be `@page "/"` and also (on another line) `@page "/index"`

Comment: Thanks Bennyboy, but I still do not know what should I name the razor page File that loads the details for each employee.

Comment: Anything you like.   It's the `@page` that defines the route, not the class name.  For example navigating to `/` takes you to `Index.razor`.

Comment: Ah, good point.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: --edit-- wow I spelled Shaun's name wrongly.  Updated.

Comment: Thanks guys, it is clear and It works just fine